# Divide each values in rows of different data frames by values stored in vector

Tags: r

I have two data frames df1 and df2 and they are stored inside a list:

```
$df1 


column 1.  column  2.     column 3 
       A          a6          1
       B          j7          2
       C          i0          3
       D          b2          4

$df2
    column 1.  column  2.  column 3 
       E          8h          1
       F          4d          2
       G          3n          3
       H          a9          4
       I          5%          5
       L          *9.         6
```

The data frames have different row numbers and are stored in list1
list1<-(df1,df2)

I would like to divide the last column number 3 which represents the rank by the total number of row (divide each value):
The row number information is stored in a vector and it is different from the row numbers of those two data frames because they are a subset of a larger data frame with more rows:
vec<-c(10,20)

Output:

```
$df1 
$df1 nrow = 4
#df1_ALL nrow = 10
column 1.  column  2.  column 3 
   A          a6          1/10
   B          j7          2/10
   C          i0          3/10
   D          b2          4/10
$df2
$df2 nrow=6
$df2_ALL nrow = 20
column 1.  column  2.  column 3 
   E          8h          1/20
   F          4d          2/20
   G          3n          3/20
   H          a9          4/20
   I          5%          5/20
   L          *9.         6/20
```

I wrote something like this:

```
list2<-list()

for (i in 1: length(list1)) {
+   list2[[i]]<- sweep(list1[[i]]$column3, 1,vec,'/')
+ }
```

however is giving me the following error:

```
Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In sweep(myfiles[[i]]$rank, 1, g1, "/") :
  STATS is longer than the extent of 'dim(x)[MARGIN]'
```

Any help it would be great, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the `list` of datasets, with `Map` and `transform` to divide the last column by the number of rows of that dataset stored in a `vector` ('vec')

```
Map(function(x, y) transform(x, `column 3` = `column 3`/y), list1, vec)
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, I tried your code, sorry, yes that is correct when I want to divide the column 3 by the number of the rows of the data frame.

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini  Sorry, what is the issue

Comment: Now, let's suppose the row number is not 4 or 6 but it is some other number stored inside a vector such as 10 and 20, vec<-c(10,20), how to make this division?

Comment: Because those two data frames are a subset of a larger data frame, like df1 is a subset of the data frame df_ALL which instead has 10 rows

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini  Okay, please check the updated post.  with `Map`

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks a lot, I was using "Sweep" but with "Map" is better, now it is working, I wrote something like this in a for loop:

Comment: for(df in 1:length(list1)) {
  list1[[i]]$rank.perc3 <- unlist(transform(list1[[i]]$column3/vec[[i]]))
}.    This also works based on your code with transform

Comment: I voted for your answer (it is very helpful) but I have less than 15 of reputation so it says it is not showing, anyway thanks a lot for your help